# Difference between running pyspark code by using commend python3 and pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I am confused by what's difference between running code using command `python3 CODENAME.py` and launch it by commend `pyspark` and start working on the code.

When I run the code : `spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.driver.memory", "16").appName("EDA").getOrCreate()`

The first way `python3 CODENAME.py` raises the error even if I have already done

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
export SPARK_HOME=/home/twotwo/anaconda3/envs/yolov5/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$PATH
```

The error message look like:

> Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number

However ,the second way runs the code without any problem, I would like to know what's the difference between these two ways.